# Whereabouts of the Pleiades

Tags: galaxy, milky-way, star-cluster

I assume they should be in the Milky Way galaxy. I have read about it a little but did not find information on where they are.

Which galaxy do the Pleiades belong to?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the exception of the Andromeda galaxy and the [Magellanic clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magellanic_Clouds)<sup>1</sup>, every star, star cluster and nebula that is visible to the naked eye is part of the Milky Way. The Pleiades is a star cluster in the Milky Way.

Objects in other galaxies are too far and too dim to be visible with the naked eye.

<sup>1</sup><sub>The Triangulum galaxy (M33) may also be visible to the naked eye from a dark site to trained observers with excellent vision</sub>

Comment: The Triangulum galaxy (M33) is also visible to the naked eye from a dark site. It's believed to be more distant than the Andromeda galaxy, so is probably the most distant object you can see unaided in normal circumstances. (GRB_080319B was briefly naked-eye visible but it's unlikely that anyone actually noticed it.)

Answer (score 13):

To give you a perspective the Milky Way Galaxy is between 150,000 and 200,000 light years in across.  The Pleiades is less than 450 light years from Earth.  In a galactic perspective the Pleiades is incredibly close to us and so clearly within the Milky Way Galaxy.

Comment: The Pleiades are about 1.7% farther from the center of the galaxy than we are.

Comment: According to [the annotated roadmap to our galaxy](http://web.archive.org/web/20170520144949/www.spitzer.caltech.edu/images/1925-ssc2008-10b-A-Roadmap-to-the-Milky-Way-Annotated) the Milky Way galaxy is approx 160,000 light years in diameter. If you are in space looking toward the galactic center (Sagittarius A*) then Pleiades cluster (taurus constellation) is approximately in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 7):

This screen grab from the program *[Where is M13?](http://www.thinkastronomy.com/M13/)* shows the location of the Sun and Pleiades in our galaxy.

[image]

The Sun is the orange dot, the Pleiades the yellow dot.